# spring flatfile : block read null last line

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have method, that takes in a uploaded csv flat file, processes it and prints all the values.

Problem is, it still tries to read in the last time and processes the value and throws nullpointerexception error. how do i do it. ?

at the end of the loop, i have added, `while (newPs != null)` so it should not process the loops any more.

```
public void readPsFile(MultipartFile batchFile) throws Exception {  
    FlatFileItemReader<ProductService> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    DelimitedLineTokenizer delimitedTokeniser = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    delimitedTokeniser.setNames(new String[]{ "name"});
    DefaultLineMapper<ProductService> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<ProductService>();
    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(delimitedTokeniser);
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<ProductService>() {{setTargetType(ProductService.class);}});
    ByteArrayResource y= new ByteArrayResource(batchFile.getBytes());
    reader.setResource(y);
    reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1); //do not read the first line of the csv file.
    reader.open(new ExecutionContext());

    reader.open(new ExecutionContext());
    ProductService newPs = null;
    do {
        try {
        newPs = reader.read();
        System.out.println("--->"+newPs.getName());
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } while (newPs != null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're testing it too late, after you had already tried to dereference the null when calling `getName()`. Don't use `do/while` for this:

```
while ((newPs = reader.read()) != null) {
    System.out.println("--->"+newPs.getName())
}
```

Comment: `do/while` is an essential language construct, but you will find you only use it say 1% as often as `while/do`.